# JavaScript canvas.drawImage alpha loss

Tags: javascript, html, image, canvas

Pretty new to JavaScript.

I'm building a site that compares the template image with the user's input and builds some image processing directives. The template image is stored in the site's folder.

```js
$(function() {
 $("#btnDirective").click(generateEmoteDirectiveFile);
});

function generateEmoteDirectiveFile() {
 getImageData('imgs/templates/human.png');
}

function getImageData(source) {
    var image = new Image();
 
    image.onload = function () {
        var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
        canvas.width = this.naturalWidth;
        canvas.height = this.naturalHeight;
  
        var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
  ctx.drawImage(this, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  var data = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height).data;

  for (var px = 0, cx = canvas.width * canvas.height * 4; px < cx; px += 4)
   if (data[px+3] != 255 && data[px+3] != 0)
    console.log("Alpha: " + data[px+3]);
  
    };
 image.src = source;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <script src="scripts/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
  <script src="scripts/script.js"></script>
 </head>
 <body>
  <button id="btnDirective">Generate</button>
 </body>
</html>
```

['imgs/templates/human.png'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OUNok.png) contains a lot of semitransparent values, that are never fetched:

Comment: This image doesn't contain **semi** -transparent pixels. Only fully opaque or fully transparent ones.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you are trying to get the integer values for each pixel where it's alpha value of neither 0 nor 255?

Well, your image has pixels that are either full transparent, or they are solid white/black. So you will have no partially-transparent pixels.

See the image of the chili pepper emoji from Emojipedia that is used below. Around ~6% of its pixels are partially transparent (around the borders).

```js
$(function() {
  $('#btnDirective').click(generateEmoteDirectiveFile);
});

function generateEmoteDirectiveFile() {
  getImageData('https://i.imgur.com/4LzuX3G.png');
  getImageData('https://i.imgur.com/R7g697w.png'); // Using a testable image
}

function getImageData(source) {
  var image = new Image();

  image.crossOrigin = 'Anonymous'; // This allows Imgur CORS...

  image.onload = function() {
    var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
    canvas.width = this.naturalWidth;
    canvas.height = this.naturalHeight;

    document.body.appendChild(canvas); // Add canvas to body...

    var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
    ctx.drawImage(this, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    var data = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height).data;

    var pixels = canvas.width * canvas.height;
    var alphaValues = [];
    for (var px = 0, cx = pixels * 4; px < cx; px += 4) {
      if (data[px + 3] != 255 && data[px + 3] != 0) {
        alphaValues.push(data[px + 3]);
      }
    }
    var nonAlphaPixels = (alphaValues.length / pixels * 100).toFixed(2);
    console.log('Alpha (' + nonAlphaPixels + '%): ' + alphaValues.join(','));
  };

  image.src = source;
}

function drawPartialPixels(imageData) {
  
}
```

```css
body { background: #444; }
#btnDirective { display: block; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="btnDirective">Generate</button>
```

Here is an example of drawing only the partial pixels.

```js
$(function() {
  $('#btnDirective').click(generateEmoteDirectiveFile);
});

function generateEmoteDirectiveFile() {
  getImageData('https://i.imgur.com/R7g697w.png', onImageLoad);
}

function getImageData(source, onLoadFn) {
  var image = new Image();
  image.src = source;
  image.crossOrigin = 'Anonymous'; // This allows Imgur CORS...
  image.onload = function() {
    onLoadFn(this);
  };
}
  
function onImageLoad(image) {
  var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
  var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

  canvas.width = image.naturalWidth;
  canvas.height = image.naturalHeight;

  ctx.drawImage(image, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  var imageData = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  var pixels = canvas.width * canvas.height;
  for (var px = 0, cx = pixels * 4; px < cx; px += 4) {
    var partialAlpha = imageData.data[px + 3] != 255 && imageData.data[px + 3] != 0;
    imageData.data[px + 0] = partialAlpha ? 255 : 0;
    imageData.data[px + 1] = partialAlpha ?   0 : 0;
    imageData.data[px + 2] = partialAlpha ?   0 : 0;
    imageData.data[px + 3] = partialAlpha ? 255 : 0;
  }
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  ctx.putImageData(imageData, 0, 0);
  
  document.body.appendChild(canvas); // Add canvas to body...
}
```

```css
body { background: #444; }
#btnDirective { display: block; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="btnDirective">Generate</button>
```